# Django Programming Error: Cannot Cast Type bigint to uuid

Tags: python, django, web, django-rest-framework

I'm facing an issue while trying to change the data type of a column in my Django model from bigint to uuid in a PostgreSQL database. The error message I'm encountering is:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type bigint to uuid
LINE 1: ...me_studentrest" ALTER COLUMN "id" TYPE uuid USING "id"::uuid
```

Comment: Does your database already have some data where `id` is `bigint`? If yes, run a migration for them first.